# Show a ToolTip in DataGrid from MouseLeftButtonDown event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which contains some data. I added a column to it from which the user can delete rows. I want to display a ToolTip from the MouseLeftButtonDown event.

The problem is that there are some rows which the user can't delete. That's why I need to notify him with a ToolTip depending on the state of the row. My code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Image Height="20" Width="20"  Source="{Binding Action}" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"                                    
                   x:Name="ActionParameter"
                   MouseLeftButtonDown ="ActionParameter_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <Image.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock>This is a linked parameter you can't edit it !</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Image.ToolTip>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Using that XAML code the ToolTip will always be shown. I've tried to test the row using the mouse left button but I don't find a way to do that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you either disable the delete image, or show a different image when you can/cannot delete, etc.?  Give the user a visual clue so he/she doesn't need to click on every row to see which may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `Image` XAML declaration:

```
ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False"
```

Then in your `ActionParameter_MouseLeftButtonDown` you can use:

```
    void ActionParameter_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ... // compute canDelete

        if (cantDelete)
        {
           Image img = (Image)sender;
           ToolTipService.SetIsEnabled(img, true);

           // Uncomment if you want to immediately open it
           // ((ToolTip)img.ToolTip).IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
```

Notice that if you uncomment to programmatically open the ToolTip, it'll stay open until you close it or your Window loses focus.